# Should we average weight decay loss in neural network?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, regularization

In a typical neural network, which way is the common way to add regularization?

Assuming regression task, regression error loss is Mean-squared-error

Then we can have two choice of regularization on weights:

1. $\lambda$ * $\sum ||W||^2$
2. $\lambda$ * $\textbf{average} ||W||^2$

I have seen most people use the *first* option, just being curious to ask.

Comment: depending on what you mean by average, the two should be equivalent as they differ by the scalar value of the number of samples.

Comment: What are you summing/averaging over? It's not clear from your expressions

Comment: Is the difference between the two, the second $\lambda$ will be $\lambda/n$ of the original? If so, im not sure if it really matters much.

Comment: I agree with @AnonymousEmu, it's just a different scale for lambda variable. With average you just reduce value of the lambda implicitly

Answer (score 1):

Using the average implicitly rescales $\lambda$. This means that choosing the average or the sum isn't really consequential, because whatever the optimal $\lambda$ is on the mean scale has an equivalent choice of $\lambda$ on the sum scale, and vice versa. 
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda \sum_i w_i^2 &= \lambda\sum_iw_i^2 \\
 &= {n\lambda} \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_iw_i^2 \right]\\
\end{align}
$$